# Is there any way to find google cast devices if your app isn't using an AppCompat derived theme?

Tags: android, android-activity, chromecast

I recently started working on an nearly completed android app, and was tasked with adding chromecast integration.  The problem I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to get the MediaRouteActionProvider from my menu item because the app isn't based off an AppCompat derived theme (IIRC, it's mostly Holo).

For instance, in all of the example apps I've looked at, there is some code like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflator().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem caster = menu.findItem(R.id.chromecast_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider actionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(caster);
    actionProvider.setRouteSelected(routeSelector);
    return true;
}
```

But the actionProvider decleration returns null for an app that isn't AppCompat based.

Are there any other options for getting chromecast devices on the network?

Comment: You can try my port of `MediaRouteActionProvider` that works with the native API Level 11+ action bar: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks!  I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, having a bit of trouble with it.  I have my menu item set with your MediaRouteActionProvider.  Then when I inflate the menu, and add my routeSelector to my MediaRouter, if I check provide.isVisible() it returns false any the route select button doesn't show up.  However, nearly the exact same code works fine in your demo app.  Any ideas?

Comment: Other than "it must have to do with the differences", I do not have any suggestions. You could open up a separate Stack Overflow question, providing your code (particularly those differences), and that may give me some ideas.